# HTML tag <hr> behind <div>

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="my_div" style="height:400px"></div>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="my_input">
```

**my_div** will be populated with data later (via jQuery) but the thing is that the

```
<hr>
```

appears behind **my_div** but **my_input** is where it should be (that is, after **my_div**).

Does anyone know why?

EDIT: A bootstrap css class (span10) was causing this problem. After I removed that class, it worked.

Comment: do you change the style of the div in jquery ?

Comment: Maybe you want `overflow: auto`

Comment: If you remove the height attribute altogether does that fix the issue?  I have experienced a similar problem in the past. Not declaring a height fixed it.

Comment: @ionutvmi I am not changing the style in jQuery

Comment: Is there any more code? I can't reproduce the problem http://jsfiddle.net/esgHz/

Comment: @Explosion Pills overflow:auto didn't help... :(

Comment: @showdev You're not adding content to the div. http://jsfiddle.net/cfnQe/

I'm just not sure what the desired behavior is. Do you want the div to scroll or expand to fit the added content?

Comment: @showdev I am actually using Bootstrap. I don't know if that is messing up things...

Comment: @meub I just add things to my_div later. But even before adding anything, <hr> already appears behind it...

Comment: @averageman Could be. I suggest checking a development console (like FireBug) to see what CSS styles are applied to `#my_div` and related elements. See if removing bootstrap css files fixes the problem.

Comment: More code is required to diagnose this issue. It could be positioning, overflow, float or any number of things.

Comment: Upload your entire problematic code block to http://www.jsFiddle.net

Comment: Here is a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/HpuSc/ that works without problems , i guess your content contains some html or css that change format of your page.

Comment: So much guessing and so many answers yet so little effort and input from the OP. Why is this question still even open!!!

Comment: I found a Bootstrap css class (span10) that, after removed, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give your div a `position: relative` value

```
<div id="my_div" style="height:400px; position: relative;"></div>
```

For testing purposes only, i would give your CSS a declaration of `!important` just to rule out any javascript/ bootstrap override

```
<div id="my_div" style="height:400px !important; position: relative !important;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: To rule out javascript/ bootstrap position: absolute possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the information you've provided, I think it might depend on the content you're placing into it. As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5RZ3j/1/), the `<hr>` is displaying below the div, as it should.

One case I can think of that might be causing this is if you're inserting content that is floated using CSS inside the div. In that case, the div will "shrink" to the height of the last in-flow (not floated) element it contains, which will make it shrink to a height of 0 if there are no non-floated elements inside it.

If that is your case, then you can work around that by adding the following CSS to your `#my_div`:

```
#my_div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

There are also other workarounds for this kind of problem, but this one is the easiest to try out in order to check if that's the problem affecting you.

---

Another issue that could possibly be affecting you is that the height of the div is restricted to 400px. If the content of the div exceeds that height, it won't push the div's boundaries down, but instead it will overflow ([quick demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/T8Bbd/1/)). If that's the case, you can either set the div's `height` to `auto`, so that it will stretch along with the content, or you can make sure the content won't get past the div's height by tweaking it.

Answer (score 1):

A bootstrap css class (span10) was causing this issue. After removing it from **my_div**, it worked.

Comment: It says I can only accept it in 2 days. But it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

set the position of both to relative and see if they appear properly

Answer (score 0):

It's because your div has fixed height of 400px. It may be overflowed by the content, but it can't move other blocks further than its specified height. Probably you need to set to it `min-height: 400px` instead of `height: 400px`.

Comment: Not a bad idea. But OP says "even before adding anything, <hr> already appears behind [my_div]"

Comment: Isn't this `div` floating or absolutely positioned?

Answer (score -1):

A div without content is displayed as height=zero. Try inserting a

```
&nbsp;
```

inside the div so that it is displayed as 400px in height initially.

Answer (score -1):

i think jquery first remove your "my_div" then append to your container.
try this fix

```
<div id="yourContainer">
            <div id="my_div" style="height:400px"></div>
            <hr>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourContainer').find('hr').remove();
    $('#yourContainer').append('<hr />');
});
```

Comment: Those kind of problems can be easily solved in CSS, no need to use JS.